# Python Flask call index function without refresh page?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

```
from flask import Flask,render_template 

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
     print('hello') 
     return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
     app.run(debug=True)
```

the index function is run whenever there is a request, so it is pressed on the "hello" console screen every time the site is refreshed or entered. So how can I always print "hello" in real time without refreshing this page?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you please explain your intent further?  From what I can tell, you want to execute some function continually, but I suspect that isn't your intent at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean, saying "always"?

When you run flask app it starts in main thread, so if you want to make some worker(who for example prints your hello word), just create a new thread, and put in there.
Example:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template 
import threading,time

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
def start_new_thread():
    def worker(arg1,arg2):
        while(True):
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(2)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=("your argument","sencond one"))
    thread.start();
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_new_thread()
    app.run(debug=True)
    print("OK")#never be printed because app.run starts in main thread
```

Comment: Yes, works fine.Thanks for support man. I mean "always" while loop.